# Difference Between *list and **list

Tags: c, pointers, struct

If I have a struct:

```
typedef struct A
{
   char c[100];
}A;
```

Then I create a

```
sizeOfA = 5000;
A *list = (A*) malloc(sizeOfA * sizeof(A));
```

Is `list[i]` a pointer to a struct?

Or if I want a pointer to the struct, should I do

```
A **list = (A**) malloc (sizeOfA * sizeof(A*);
```

**[EDIT]**

<strike>Now let's say I created the list using `A *list` (which I did already). How would I create 5000 pointers and make them point to the elements on the list?</strike>

```
p0 -> list[0]
p1 -> list[1]
..
..
p[n] -> list[n]
```

After going back and forth a few times I noticed that for sorting the pointers help a lot.

To be fair I will post the edit above as a separate question.

Comment: Ewww. Sorry but this code is horrible. First, one [must not cast the return value of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858). Second, the variable name `sizeOfA` is an extremely bad choice, especially when used in conjunction with `sizeof A`. Furthermore, use `sizeof(*pointer)` instead of `sizeof(TYPE)` to be safe in case the base type of the pointer ever changes. All in all, the proper way to write that line would be `A *list = malloc(list_length * sizeof(*list));`

Comment: is list_length just my sizeOfA variable with a different name?

Comment: Yes it is -- it's just a more descriptive and less confusing name. (Still feel free to write it as `listLength` if you prefer camel case.)

Comment: Yeah I prefer camel case. I like what you have just taught me, much better indeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After this statement:

```
A *list = (A*) malloc(sizeOfA * sizeof(A));
```

`list` is a pointer to the starting location of a memory block that can hold `sizeOfA` elements of type `struct A`. Thus, `*list` is of type `struct A`, and similarly, `list[i]` is of type `struct A`, not pointer to `struct A` (that would be `list+i`).

If you want `list[i]` to be a pointer to `struct A`, then your second piece of code would be the correct one, since you're allocating a memory location with enough space to hold `sizeOfA` pointers to `struct A`. Note that you are only allocating space to hold pointers, not actual `struct A` instances. Attempting to read `list[i]->c` will result in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
A *list = (A*) malloc(sizeOfA * sizeof(A));
Is list[i] a pointer to a struct?
```

No -- `list` is a pointer to an address in the heap, which is the start of a memory chunk that has size `sizeOfA * sizeof(A)`. `list[i]` is the same thing as `*(list + i)`, which is a dereference that will give you an actual `A`.

However..

```
A **list = (A**) malloc (sizeOfA * sizeof(A*);
Is list[i] a pointer to a struct?
```

Yup.

Comment: Right, but the latter being useless until it is actually filled with valid pointers. Only then they can be used.