# Assigning a Pointer to Every Element on a List

Tags: c, pointers, struct

*This question builds up on my previous question: [Difference Between *list and **list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19464082/difference-between-list-and-list). I decided to split them into two questions to make it less confusing, clear, and fair for people answering.*

I have this code:

```
typedef struct A
{
   char c[100];
}A;

listSize = 5000; 

A *list = malloc(listSize * sizeof(*list));
```

I want to call a function and create a pointer for every element.

**How would I create 5000 pointers and make them point to the elements on the list?**

```
p0 -> list[0]
p1 -> list[1]
..
..
p[n] -> list[n]
```

Comment: OT: `listSize = 5000;` won't compile.

Comment: Assuming it is an int, it should, no?

Comment: @MikeJohn, it should, but `size_t` is a better option

Comment: Also check the result of malloc instead of cast the return :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
A** p = malloc(listSize * sizeof(A*));
int i;
for(i = 0; i < listSize; ++i) {
    p[i] = &list[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct A
{
   char c[100];
}A;

size_t listSize = 5000; // !

A *list = malloc(listSize * sizeof(*list));
if (!list) {
    // complain about low memory and leave this part of function.
}

A** p = malloc(listSize * sizeof(A*));
if (!p) {
    // complain about low memory and leave this part of function.
    // Maybe free(list) in order not to leak memory.
}
```

Only then it is safe to write to `p`:

```
size_t i;
for(i = 0; i < listSize; ++i) {
    p[i] = &list[i];
}
```